# Picasso images are not loading for some devices

Tags: android, image, picasso

First of all, I need to say that I've tried every possible solution that I could find on stackoverflow like onImageLoadFailed, callback function, setLoggingEnabled(true) and I've just put only load() and into() but for some reason image won't load in my friend's phone but not in my phone and my emulator.

And I've put slack integration into my app but it send nothing because it couldn't produce any error trace (which I assume there is no error trace so slack send nothing in return).

I've have tried using placeholder and it shows placeholder instead of images from an API that I'm using

fyi, mine is Marshmallow and my friend is using lolipop

and here is the code that I'm currently using...

```
Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true);
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(menuDataSet.get(position).getImage_url())
       .into(image);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: put this in manifest :    android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: I already did that...

Comment: then you should have to minimise size of image before submitting to picasso.

Comment: I did that and it has no effect (the images size are already small enough)...and I also put resize(), fit(), centerCrop() with every possible combination but I got nada...the problem is the images showing up in both of my phone and emulator (including my phone's brother) but not in my friends (I just gave it to 2 of my friends for the the sake of testing)

Comment: You got any solution with this?